# Referencing jobnum within job procedure - oracle plsql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, jobs

I have job procedure which do dequeuing from advanced queue, one message at a time.When queue is empty exception should be raised and i want in exception section to remove that job, but i dont know how to referenc jobnum of that particular job.I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can query `SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'BG_JOB_ID')` to get the current session's job id

Answer (score 0):

Thx man.
In the mean time i found out that i can referenc job_id druing the creation of the job.

"When the job definition references these job parameters in its own parameter list, their values are assigned to the parameters in the job definition when the job executes. For example, suppose that a procedure called proc1 has the following specification:

PROCEDURE proc1 (my_job_number IN INTEGER);
Suppose also that we submit proc1 to be executed by the job queue as follows:

DECLARE
   jobno   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(jobno,`proc1(my_job_number=>job);');
END;
/
When proc1 is executed by the queue, the my_job_number parameter is assigned the job's job number, and thus proc1 will "know" what job number it is."

And here is the link http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/bipack/ch13_01.htm if someone also will be nedded

Thanks once again